# Change database connection inside a transaction using PDO

Tags: php, pdo, transactions

I want to change the database and do an insert while I am in a transaction. Is that possible?

this is my code

```
$db->beginTransaction();
try {

-----some code here-----

(Insert db1.table1);

(update db1.table2)

$db_new = new PDO (...);

$db_new->query("insert db2.table statement"); 

$db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
 $db->rollBack();
}
```

Am I doing it correct? But I get an error **Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction**

Why is this happening am i doing something wrong??

Comment: Are you inserting in the same table you're updating? And why not use the same connection/transaction?

Comment: $db_new connection is established to make an insert into another database

Comment: can i create a new PDO instance inside a transaction @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: You should be able to do this without a problem, sounds like you may have an active transaction locking db2.table.

Comment: no db2.table is not in any transaction

Comment: when i comment the update statement the entire code works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking - yes. You may run any code you want while your transaction is opened, as long as this code is not relevant to this transaction.

You only should make a note that there is no point in running any irrelevant code while your transaction is opened - you may run it later.

As of the error you get - it is caused by some other problem. transactions are obviously connection-based, and transaction opened in one connection would never be affected by any other connection.

Comment: but when i comment off that update statement it works fine for me. Why is that so?